# Sample MVC3 Razor application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a sample application using MVC3 with Razor, something similar to the NerdDinner website where I can review the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) has been updated for MVC3 [according to the CodePlex changeset in August `11](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/68571).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [MVC3 Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1)

Answer (score 2):

Check for MVC Music Store [MVC MusicStore](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/), but check for the lastest committed versions, as the last committed version have some problems.

1. Check for tampaDev site. [Tampadev.org mvc3 samples](http://tampadev.org/News/Details/aspnetmvcsampleapplicationsopensourceexamplestutorials)
2. Codeplex tagged projects [Codeplex Asp.net mvc3](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=%22ASP.NET%20MVC%22&sortBy=Relevance&tagName=,ASP.NET%20MVC,ASP.NET%20MVC%203,&licenses=%7C&refinedSearch=true)

Answer (score 0):

Refer the book "Pro ASP.Net MVC3 Framework" By Adam Freeman and Steven Sanderson. They are clearly explaining MVC3 Pattern, its language features and essential tools for MVC3. In addition, it demonstrates step by step development of a sample sport store application with source code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good stuff I think in `Applied ASP.NET 4 In Context` [http://www.amazon.com/Applied-ASP-NET-Context-Adam-Freeman/dp/1430234679](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234679). There's an example ASP.NET MVC application!

Good luck!